# Unclear proof in the Gauss-Markov theorem

Tags: matrices, least-squares

I don't understand a step in the proof of the Gauss-Markov theorem:
[image: proof]

Mainly, why can we simply replace y with e, given that y is defined as:
[image: y definition]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute the $y = W\beta + e$ into the $y-W[(W'W)^{-1}W'+C]y$ (expression ahead of the red line you draw) yield:

> $e - W(W'W)^{-1}W'e - WCW\beta - WCe = e - W(W'W)^{-1}W'e - WCe$

thanks to $CW=0.$

I guess the last sign in the bracket should be $-$.